# How to access to the length of the dynamic string, sent as the print argument within the same print method?

Tags: python

One might be eager to send a string to the print method, is which consists of some dynamic parameters. Just assume that the final length of the very string argument should be printed by format method. what is the required approach for this aim?

```
code = int(input("Get the code: "))
name = "Anonymous"
number = 7


print("{0}'s number is {1} and the code is {2}. The final length of the string is        {3}".format(name,num,code,?))
# ? = length of {0}'s number is {1} and the code is {2}. The final length of the string is {3}
```

Comment: you should consider len(string) + len(len(string)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `len()`:

```
code = int(input("Get the code: "))
name = "Anonymous"
number = 7
print("{0}'s length is {1}".format("{0}'s number is {1} and the code is {2}. The final length of the string is {3}".format(name,number,code,len(name+str(number)+str(code))), len("{0}'s number is {1} and the code is {2}. The final length of the string is {3}".format(name,number,code,len(name+str(number)+str(code)))))
```

Comment: it's not correct! because you don't know what number will be generate! you should consider the final var length + string length!

Comment: for example I have a string : `this is test` . it has 12 length. if you want to get output of `this is test {0}` it should be 12 + 1 + len(12). sometime length can be 20 , so len(string) + len(len(string) works fine.

Comment: @aj8uppal: No!!! It is not the answer. As I illustrated I need the full length of the print argument, is which variable with due attention to the value entered by user for code. Actually I need the length of this:
"{0}'s number is {1} and the code is {2}. The final length of the string is {3}"

Comment: @matinking can you explain with some example input/output?

Comment: @aj8uppal: if the user enter 111 for the code value the final out put should be the length of below string:
"Anonymous's number is 7 and the code is 111. The final length of the string is {3}"
Which should be :83

Comment: @aj8uppal: That works!... Thank you. However I am prone to figure something out to access to the final length without using any temp just like string variable you've used. In the other word, computation and printing the final length with no temp!
Do you think that it is feasible?!

Comment: @aj8uppal: You hit the mark!... Good Job!
Except you've missed a ) at the end of the last line :)
Thank you